# JOptionPane button size (Nimbus LAF)

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, nimbus, uimanager

Recently I've been working on a Swing project with Nimbus Look and Feel. I want to set all buttons in a JOptionPane to have the same size, but in vain.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class NimbusTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {    
                try {
                    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if (("Nimbus").equals(info.getName())) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                UIManager.put("OptionPane.sameSizeButtons", true);    
                String[] options = new String[]{"--------------------","short","1"};
                int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Nimbus problem", "JOptionPane", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I want is a JOptionPane with three buttons having the same size. However, I got the following result:

[image]

My code `UIManager.put("OptionPane.sameSizeButtons", true);` seems to be ignored. What should I do to create a JOptionPane with same size buttons if I don't want to recreate a JOptionPane-like dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
 UIManager.put("OptionPane.sameSizeButtons", true);
```

with

```
 UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("OptionPane.sameSizeButtons", true);
```

And it works like a charm

[image]

Comment: How do I set the size in pixels?

Comment: @EthanJCRubik if needed, you extend jbutton and override getpreferedsize